# Write a chrome extension to console.log the active tab URL whenever a new page is loaded

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

I want to write a chrome extension which records the current active tab URL every time a new site is loaded and send it to a server for further use. So far I have managed to write the following code:
**manifest.json**

```
{
    "manifest_version": 2,
    "name": "Currenturl",
    "description": "Fetches current tab url.",
    "version": "0.1",
    "author": "Tarun Khare",
    "browser_action": {
        "default_icon": "icon.png",
        "default_title": "Just observing your current url."
    },
    "permissions": ["tabs", "activeTab"],
    "background": {
        "scripts": ["content.js"],
        "persistent": false
    }
}
```

**content.js**

```
chrome.tabs.query({'active': true, 'lastFocusedWindow': true}, function (tabs) {
    var url = tabs[0].url;
    console.log("hello: "+url);
});
```

I am using background scripts since chrome.tabs doesn't work in content scripts. But this extension is not printing anything in chrome console. What is the issue?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Rename content.js to background.js since this is a background script
2. Use [chrome.tabs.onUpdated](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/tabs#event-onUpdated) listener
3. Look at the correct console: [Where to read console messages from background.js?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10258029)

---

```
chrome.tabs.onUpdated.addListener((tabId, change, tab) => {
  if (change.url) {
    console.log(change.url);
  }
});
```

It'll report the URL changes in all tabs.
You can also limit the processing to only the active tab by adding a check for [tab.active](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/tabs#type-Tab) property.

Comment: can you tell the code to get current focussed tab's url?

Comment: It's the code in your question, but it's not a listener.

Answer (score 0):

i try to write code based on the information you provide.

```
const tabUpdatelistenerFun = (tabid, changeInfo, tab) => {
  const url = changeInfo.url;

  if (!url || ['chrome://', 'about://'].some(p => url.startsWith(p))) return false;

  const { index, active, highlighted, windowId } = tab;

  if (!active) return false;

  chrome.tabs.query({ index, highlighted, windowId, lastFocusedWindow: true }, () => {
    console.log(url);
  })
}

chrome.tabs.onUpdated.addListener(tabUpdatelistenerFun);
```

i think this is what you want.

Answer (score 0):

You can count and extract the URL with full detail in **background.js**
here is the main code from below GihHub repository:

```
    chrome.windows.getAll({ populate: true }, function (windows) {
    windows.forEach(function (window) {
    window.tabs.forEach(function (tab) {
    //i++
    collect all of the urls here, I will just log them instead
    console.log("tab.ur[![enter image description here][1]][1]l aaaaakahari 2");
        console.log(tab.url);
    });
  });
});
```

There is a GitHub repository of chrome Extension below here, you can find in the **background.js** there are methods to count and extract the open URL, and there is and even section that console it imminently when the user open or close any tab.

https://github.com/Farbod29/extract-and-find-the-new-tab-frome-the-browser-with-chrome-extention